# C# Why is a &= SomeFunction() executed if a == false?

Tags: c#, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

Let's say you have

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        bool a = GetFalse();
        if (a)
        {
            a = GetTrue();
        }

        bool b = GetFalse();
        b &= GetTrue();
    }

    static bool GetFalse() => (false);

    static bool GetTrue() => (true);
}
```

Why will `GetTrue()` be executed when `b` is already false?

Shouldn't the `&=` operator recognize that it can never evaluate to true?

Comment: No - the `&=` operator is equivalent to `x = x & y` and does not short-circuit.

Comment: A simpler explanation is that & is a bitwise operator, and to perform a bitwise operation you need the binary value of both operands, therefore you need to execute the second part even if the first is false.

Comment: @zoubida13 `&`is only a bitwise operator on integral types - they are both boolean operators on boolean types.

Comment: @DStanley This is what I am [probably not so well] trying to say. To apply the bitwise operation (ie bit by bit) it needs to process both operands beforehand, and convert integral types if necessary.
&& is a logical operator in c#, not bitwise, it will take the boolean value of operand 1 and then decide to proceed with the boolean value of operand two. Although I admit we may be arguing on semantics here.

Comment: It's not semantics.  `&` is a non-short-circuiting _logical_ operator for boolean types.  There is a common misconception that `&` is bitwise and `&&` is logical.  They are _both_ logical for boolean types; the only difference is one short-circuits and one doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

Because `x &= y` is simply shorthand for `x = x & y`. `&` is not *short-circuited*, so `y` is evaluated regardless of the value of `x`, even for bools.

For bools, specifically, there *is* a short-circuited version of `&`: `&&`. There's no `&&=` operator, though, so you need to do it separately:

```
b = b && GetTrue();
```

Comment: Is there a short-circuit equivalent?

Comment: @roryap Not in one operator - you have to use `x = x && y`